# Data binding not working in a modal dialog when triggered from an ActionItem in a Nativescript Angular project

Tags: angular, nativescript

I have a simple component consists of a list view binding to a string array.  When I use ModalDialogService's showModal method to launch the dialog from my home component, everything works.

[Screen shot of data binding working in a modal dialog launched from a button on a home component](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3NOB1.png)

However, if I tried to launch the same dialog from the 'tap' event of an ActionBar item, all elements with binding would not show up.

[Screen shot of empty element in a modal dialog launched from an actionbar item](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gdu6y.png)

I've uploaded a simple project to Github to demonstrate this issue.  Not sure if it is a bug or I missed anything.

https://github.com/sr3dna/IssueDemo

Here is my function to launch the dialog, nothing unusual:

```
    launchDialog() {

    let selections: string[] = ["car", "airplane", "boat"];
    const options: ModalDialogOptions = {
        viewContainerRef: this.viewContainerRef,
        context: selections
    };
    this.modalService.showModal(TestDialogComponent, options)
        .then((args) => {
            alert(`Item selected = [${args}]`);
        });
    }
```

Here is how I call the launchDialog function from the 'tap' event:

```
let newActionItem = new ActionItem();
    newActionItem.text = "Select Item";
    newActionItem.on("tap", (args) => {

        this.launchDialog();

        // I even tried adding setTimeout but no luck.
        // setTimeout(() => {
        //     this.launchDialog();
        // }, 1000)

    })
    this.page.actionBar.actionItems.addItem(newActionItem);
```

Any help would be much appreciated,

Andy

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.  I need to use NgZone.

Here is what I've added

```
constructor(
    ...
    private zone: NgZone
) {}

...
    newActionItem.on("tap", (args) => {
        this.zone.run(() => {
            this.launchDialog();
        })
    })
```

I've updated the codes here:
https://github.com/sr3dna/IssueDemo

Thanks,
Andy